# Encontrar os elementos de uma classe eno jQuery e acrescentar-lhes um parâmetro

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Preciso fazer uma função em jQuery ou JavaScript, que encontre todos os itens com uma determinada **classe css** e adicione um parâmetro para essa classe, uma cor diferente por exemplo.

> Vou colocar em um botão, depois de clicar a primeira vez, na segunda vez ele tem que remover esse parâmetro.

```html
<button type="button" id="btn">Clique</button>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a função [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) do jQuery se pretende adicionar ou remover a cada clique no botão, exemplo:

```js
$("#btn").click(function(){
  $(".mudar").toggleClass("tx-blue");
});
```

```css
.tx-blue{
  color:blue;  
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn">Clique</button>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
```

Comment: Exatamente isso que eu queria amigo, muito obrigado.

Answer (score 3):

Acho que é isso o que você quer:

```js
var contaCliques = 0;
$("#btn").click(function() {
    if (contaCliques == 0) {
        $(".mudar").addClass("outraCor");
        contaCliques++;
    } else {
        $(".mudar").removeClass("outraCor");
    }
});
```

```css
.outraCor {
     background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button type="button" id="btn">Clique</button>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
```

Clique no botão azul "**Executar**" acima e veja funcionando.

Ao executar, na primeira vez que você clicar no botão "**Clique**", ele adiciona a cor e na segunda vez ele retira. Da terceira vez em diante, nada acontece.

Answer (score 0):

Veja o código abaixo funcionando:

```js
// JAVASCRIPT


$('#btn').click(function(){
  $(".mudar").toggleClass('red');
});
```

```css
/* CSS */
.red {
  background-color: red;
  }
```

```html
<!-- HTML -->

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<button type="button" id="btn">Clique</button>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
<div class="mudar">TEXTO QUE VAI MUDAR DE COR</div>
```

O que o [toggleClass](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) vai fazer é checar se a classe `red` existe: se não existir ele adiciona e se existir ele remove. Algo similar a:

```
  if($('.mudar').hasClass('red')){
    $('.mudar').removeClass('red');
  }else{
    $('.mudar').addClass('red');
  }
```